# If $X$ ~ $\text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$, find $\Bbb{E}\left[ X(1-X)\right]$

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

I am currently reading through John I.Marden's *Mathematical Statistics: Old School* on my own and I am trying to solve the following problem about expectation.

> If $X$ ~ $\text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$, find $\Bbb{E}\left[ X(1-X)\right]$ in terms of a rational polynomial in $\alpha ,\beta$

---

### My Attempt

I started with defining $\displaystyle \Bbb{E}\left[ X(1-X)\right] = \int_0^1 x(1-x) \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} \,x^{\alpha - 1}\, (1-x)^{\beta - 1} \, dx$

From here I moved out the constant terms and bring together common factors:

$$\frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\int_0^1  x^{\alpha}\, (1-x)^{\beta} \, dx$$

Now using the binomial theorem, we have $$\frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\int_0^1  x^{\alpha}\, \sum_{i=0}^\beta \left( \binom{\beta}{i}(-x)^i \right) \, dx$$
$$ = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\int_0^1  x^\alpha - \beta x^{\alpha + 1} + \binom{\beta}{2}x^{\alpha + 2} - \cdots + (-x)^{\alpha + \beta} \, dx $$

$$ = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} \left( \frac{1}{\alpha+1} - \frac{\beta}{\alpha+2}+\frac{\binom{\beta}{2}}{\alpha+3}- \cdots +\frac{(-1)^{\alpha+\beta+1}}{\alpha + \beta + 1} \right) $$

I am not sure if this is the answer that is wanted or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The integrand in the expression for $E[X(1-X)]$ looks like the density function for the  $\text{Beta}(\alpha+1,\beta+1)$ distribution.  So the expectation should be the ratio of the norming constants for the  $\text{Beta}(\alpha+1,\beta+1)$ and  $\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ distributions.

Comment: I see, from your approach I am getting at $E[X(1-X)]$ to be $$\frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} * \frac{\Gamma(\alpha +1)\Gamma(\beta+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + 2)}$$ is this what you mean? How should I proceed from here?

Comment: Do you know how to work out $\Gamma(a+1)$ in terms of $\Gamma(a)$?

Comment: I believe so, using the fact that $\Gamma(a+1) = (a+1)\Gamma(a)$, we can simplify the whole thing to (check my arithmetic) $$\frac{(\alpha + 1)(\beta + 1)}{(\alpha + \beta + 2)(\alpha + \beta + 1)}$$

Comment: But $\Gamma(a+1)=a\Gamma(a)$.

Comment: Ahhh, I'm not super familiar with the Gamma function really only knew that it had similarities to the factorial, but I believe from here and after fixing I can figure it out! Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

$\require{cancel}$

### For anyone interested in following along the comments

We have $\displaystyle \Bbb{E}\left[ X(1-X)\right] = \int_0^1 x(1-x) \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} \,x^{\alpha - 1}\, (1-x)^{\beta - 1} \, dx = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\int_0^1  x^{\alpha}\, (1-x)^{\beta} \, dx$

If we look at a Beta Distribution with parameters $\alpha+1$ and $\beta + 1$, we know that because probability density functions must have an area of $1$ under the curve, which leads to: $$1 = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta +2)}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)\Gamma(\beta+1)}\int_0^1  x^{\alpha}\, (1-x)^{\beta} \, dx$$
$$\implies  \int_0^1  x^{\alpha}\, (1-x)^{\beta} \, dx = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)\Gamma(\beta+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta +2)}$$

Substituting in, we have that $$\Bbb{E}\left[ X(1-X)\right] = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)\Gamma(\beta+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta +2)} $$

Now we just need to use Gamma function properties to reduce:
$$\frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)\Gamma(\beta+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta +2)} =\frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\cancel{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}}\frac{\alpha \, \cancel{\Gamma(\alpha)} \, \beta \,\cancel{\Gamma(\beta)}}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta +2)} =  \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{1}\frac{\alpha \,  \, \beta \,}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta +2)} $$

$$=\frac{\cancel{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}}{1}\frac{\alpha \,  \, \beta \,}{(\alpha + \beta + 1)(\alpha + \beta) \cancel{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}} $$

$$\bbox[yellow]{= \frac{\alpha \beta}{(\alpha + \beta)^2+ \alpha + \beta} = \Bbb{E}\left[ X(1-X)\right]}$$